# Cannot find ros.h

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am going thru the tutorial USING ROSED.

I am getting error ..

sai@sai-desktop:/opt/ros/fuerte/share/roscpp$ rosed roscpp ros.h 
That file does not exist in that package. 
sai@sai-desktop:/opt/ros/fuerte/share/roscpp$

In the manifest.xml of roscpp i added

Please help me...

Sai

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40456/cannot-find-ros.h/) by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1935 on 2012-08-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Setting a package as its own dependency cannot be good. You only add that XML line to your packages that use [roscpp](http://ros.org/wiki/roscpp).

Your output from rosed is right, since fuerte there is no *ros.h* anymore in roscpp. So the example from [the tutorial you meant](http://ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/UsingRosEd) is just outdated. I'll put a note.

---

Originally posted by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) with karma: 1650 on 2012-08-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2